# Как дождаться возврата данных из firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-database

У меня есть класс активность. В нем есть список типа User

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var list: User? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  }
}
```

И есть класс в который у меня вынесены все операции с Firebase базой данных.
В этом классе есть список User, и есть функция которая заполняет этот список данными из Firebase и возвращает этот список.

```
class FirebaseOperations {

var list: User? = null


   //Функция получения пользователя по ID

companion object{
fun getUserList(id: String){

        db?.getReference("Users")?.child(id)?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for(users in snapshot){
                   list.add(users.getValue(User::class.java)) 
}
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }

        })
        return list
    }
}
    
}
```

эту функция я вызываю в своей активности примерно так:

```
list = FirebaseOperations.getUserList()
```

Проблема в том что, запрос из Firebase выполняется асинхронно, и оператор `return` не ждет ответа от firebase и возвращает `null`

Как я могу дождаться пока firebase добавить все данные в мой список, и чтобы только после этого функция `getUserList` вернула уже заполненный список?

P.S Я хочу чтобы функция `getUserList` была именно в отдельном классе таком как `FirebaseOperations`

Comment: И да, можно сделать list статическим и публичным в MainActivity, а потом обращаться к нему в методе getUserList в onDataChange. Но ведь это нарушения принципа инкапсуляции, и такой вариант решения меня не устраивает

Comment: гугли в сторону такой вещи как LiveData. она как раз реализует то, что хочешь - выполнять определенный код, когда данные изменяются.